# How Visual Studio 2015 Publish Web app and SQL, update DB

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure, msbuild, web-deployment

starting using VS2015 and publishing to azure websites. I'm developing using a local DB for faster interaction. And I'm publishing Web Application and a SQL Database (Project > publish). But I always getting this error.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4276,5): Error ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE:
>
> "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]("  There is already an object named '__MigrationHistory' in the database" #ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE.)
>
> Publish failed to deploy.

And it is the same for every table on DB.

How can I somehow just update the tables on the server?
There is another way to work with apps and DB in local machine and later update to the server?

I'm using vs2015, webDeploy 3.6, Windows Azure web app and SQL DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this solved by removing all files from Properties\PublishProfiles. There was lots of old files from my first publishing attempts. After this I created new profile.